# Set primary swap partition

Tags: swap

Can I somehow set Ubuntu to use the first swap partion in `/dev/sdb` and only if not available (or full), use the swap partition on `/dev/sda`?

`/dev/sdb` is not always mounted so it is necessary to have a swap partition also on `/dev/sda`.

But `/dev/sda` is an SSD so I'd like to avoid writing there every time I hibernate my computer to increase its lifespan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit your `/etc/fstab` so that it lists both swap partitions and assign them the relative priority:

```
# /dev/sdbX
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx   none    swap    sw,pri=1    0   0
# /dev/sdaX
UUID=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy   none    swap    sw,pri=2    0   0
```

This way if `/dev/sdb` is not available only `/dev/sda` will be used, and if `/dev/sdb` is available `/dev/sdb` will be used and `/dev/sda` will be used only once `/dev/sdb` is full.

You can check `/dev/sdbX`'s and `/dev/sdaX`'s UUID with `sudo blkid /dev/sdbX` and `sudo blkid /dev/sdaX`.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/setting_up_swap.html

Comment: I would be better to use partition labels or UUIDs instead of kernel paths to refer to partitions, since the latter can change at every boot.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Absolutely, corrected.